# Laravel relationship with 2 keys

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table of measurements and a conversions to which is used to convert, say, cm into m.

My conversion table has the columns `id, from, to, calculation`, where `from` and `to` are database ids of my units.

I want to use a Laravel relationship to get the conversion data from my measurement model.

The keys I would like to join on are:

```
measurements.unit_id -> conversions.from
measurements.display_unit_id -> conversions.to
```

I can use a BelongsTo relationship but it seems limited to only join on one key, not two as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Laravels Eloquent ORM does not natively support composite keys. However, there are packages available which can provide such functionality. A populate package being [Compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships).